# How to Check Internet Connection using Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi I have been seeing tutorials and questions here in stack on how to check if the current user has a active connection to the internet. I am trying to do it myself but I have been having trouble on applying it in an AsyncTask.

I have tried it myself but I think I am doing something wrong, My knowledge in AsyncTasks are not that developed. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance! :D

This is my MainActivity:

```
 private Button checkIntrnetButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkIntrnetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkInternetButton);
    checkIntrnetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(isOnline())
            {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"YOU ARE ONLINE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                runner.execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"YOU ARE NOT ONLINE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

protected boolean isOnline() {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (isOnline()) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204").openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
                urlc.connect();
                boolean url = (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
                String str = String.valueOf(url);
                return str;
            } catch (IOException e) {
              }

        } else {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "ProgressDialog",
                "CHECKING NETWORK CONNECTION");
    }

}
```

Comment: Well what is it that you want to do in the async task to determine that you have internet? And what goes wrong?

Comment: Sir I am wonderinig that, how will I show a toast if there is a connection or not. Thats why I thought to add within the async. Is it right?

Comment: You did not answer my questions.

Comment: Oh sorry sir, it was very rude of me. Actually what I was trying to do is that when I press a button, before it does the action of sending or retrieving data it will first check the internet connection sir.

Answer (score 1):

You should check before running the asynctask and only once, you don't need to check again inside async.

```
if(isOnline()) {
    new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Sir I am wonderrinig that, how will I show a toast if there is a connection or not. Thats why I thought to add within the async. Is it right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what are you asking.. Once if you check internet connection and it is, your asynctask will execute. It won't check you every time for connection. Is that what you want?

Comment: oh okay sir haha. I am really sorry for the confusion. But anyways I am actually using volley for my data transfers and I thought of checking out the onErrorResponse and I have found out about "Network Error, NoConnectionError, and TimeoutError" and it help me solve the problem. But thank you anyways sir for the help, I really appreciate it you deserve an upvote :D

Comment: You should ask for error catching. And also specify that you are using Volley. In your question, you don't.

Comment: Yes sir, I apologize for that

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using volley for all my inserting and retrieving of data, I have been researching and experimenting about with the volley onErrorResponse. And I have found out about "**NetworkError, NoConnectionError, and TimeoutError**" and it help me solve the problem.

```
 @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        Toast.makeText(alcoholType.this,"THERE IS A PROBLEM WITH YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       loading.dismiss();
                   }
                    else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        Toast.makeText(alcoholType.this,"PLEASE SWITCH ON WIFI OR DATA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                     else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                       Toast.makeText(alcoholType.this,"Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }

                }
```

Thanks again for everyone that helped! :D